# Entity Framework and CROSS/OUTER APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, cross-apply, outer-apply

I want to create some test cases for Entity Framework queries that surely generate SQL commands that contain CROSS APPLY or OUTER APPLY operators.

Could someone show typical scenarios where these kind of SQL queries appear?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In LINQ 2 SQL this always results in an `APPLY`:

```
from t1 in tab1
from t2 in tab2.Where(t2 => t2.SomeCol == t1.SomeCol).Take(1)
select new { t1, t2 }
```

In EF this will either fail, or also result in an `APPLY` (I don't know which one). This is a *correlated join* which requires an `APPLY` on the SQL side.

Comment: Thank you! This gives me a CROSS APPLY query. Also if I use Take(2).DefaultIfEmpty() then an OUTER APPLY query is created.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would generate an outer apply:

```
var ListLocation = from d in dc.Department                               
                         select new DepartmentViewModel()
                         {
                            LocationID = d.LocationID,
                            ManagerName = d.Managers.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ManagerId == id).Name

                          };
```

If it doesn't work you can always pass your own query if you're using EF:

```
var q2 = context.Departments.SqlQuery("Select ...");
```

Remember though that your provider has to be SQL Server 2005 and higher, EF does not support OUTER APPLY for Oracle