# EF6 Lambda Query Error: Unable to create a constant of type ... Only primitive types of enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda

I keep getting the following error when I execute the query below. I'm not sure how else to put in my condition. I haven't been able to find the same issue with other questions that have posed the same error output.

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'Project.Models.Bill'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

The code:

```
var billResults = db.Database.SqlQuery<Bill>("exec [dbo].[sp_getBills]").AsQueryable();

var results = db.Bills.Select(
                        a => new
                        {
                            a.Id,
                            a.Col1,
                            a.Col2,
                            ErrorCount = (int) (billResults.Where(x => x.BillResultsId == a.Id).Count())
                        }).Where(a => a.Col1 == "Test123");
```

I'd appreciate any help - been stuck for the past few hours on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Comment out different parts of the query until you find out exactly what is causing the error.

Comment: @FranciscoGoldenstein It's the ErrorCount line.. but I can't think of another way to get it done.

Comment: The Where clause should be before your Select clause ;)

Comment: @drooksy Thanks, noted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that you cannot use a.Id in that expression, only constant values. a.Id depends on the Where clause of db.Bills query.

You can solve this in three ways:

1) Define a class (let's call it X) with properties Id, Col1, Col2 and ErrorCount. Remove ErrorCount from this query and instead of creating an anonymous object, create an object of type X (ErrorCount will not be set). Iterate over the collection and set ErrorCount.

2) Use CROSS APPLY using Entity Framework: read [Entity Framework and CROSS/OUTER APPLY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501002/entity-framework-and-cross-outer-apply)

It would be something like this:

```
from t1 in billResults 
from t2 in db.Bills.Where(t2 => t2.Id== t1.BillResultsId )
select new { ... }
```

3) Consider creating a Stored Procedure and use a CROSS APPLY join to achieve what you need (read about CROSS APPLY here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)

Comment: Went with the stored procedure approach. Thanks for the link about cross apply... learnt something new! +1