# entity framework select person with iunclude only one child

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

lets say I have a Person class which contains list of child.

Not I would like to query database to get list of person with child inlcuded:

```
return context.Person.Include(p => p.Children);
```

Ok now I would like to modify that query so as a result I get list of Person but with only one child (lets say the oldest one sort by age desc)

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16501677/2224701, but do not expect to have that one chlild available via `person.Children` collection, it will be `new {person, child}`.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe could be achieved by a query like this:

```
from p in Persons
from ch in p.Children.OrderByDescending(x => x.Age).Take(1)
select new { p,ch }
```

Instead of `Take(1)` you can also use `FirstOrDefault()`: the resultset would then include also persons with no children:

```
from p in Persons
select new { p, p.Children.OrderByDescending(x => x.Age).FirstOrDefault() }
```

However the collection `Children` of a `Person` class is maintained automatically as a collection of all the `Children` of 1 `Person` instance and this meaning cannot be changed.

So as far as I know it is not possible, you need to create a new class containing that 1 Person + that 1 instance of Child.

Answer (score 0):

I created a library for some cases like this.

https://github.com/deyunote/EntityFramework.Include

Using this library, you can describe as below

```
context.Person.Include(p => p.Children,
                       p => p.Children.OrderByDescending(x => x.Age).Take(1).ToList())
              .ToListWithInclude(); //Async:ToListWithAsync()
```